# preg_match delimeters - not getting a match

Tags: preg-match

I need to write a php preg_match to identify a price between some tags in a bit of html I have stored in a variable:

`<span class="price-ld">250</span>`

I tried writing it like this, but it keeps giving me errors:

`preg_match('/<span class="price-ld">(.*)/i', $candidate[0], $price);`

I am very new to php and all these delimeters is very heavy to me. I would really appreciate some help from you pros - probably very easy to you!

Comment: Make sure `$price` is an array, not a string variable. The part of the string matching the RE between `()` will be in `$price[1]`.

Comment: Still looking for an answer guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - read it, please.
Then you see that /(.*)/i matches a whole string.

Please, give here your piece of html (it's needed to know the price wrapping tags).

Comment: `<span class="price-ld">250</span>`

Comment: It wasnt returning any errors as such - just not making a match even though I know that `$candidate[0]` contains a match..

Comment: Did you succeed? Just leave it here:
preg_match('/<span class="price-ld">[0-9]*</span>/i', $candidate[0], $price);